# Devolver los valores de una lista que nos pasan y que no encuentra en la tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla ARTICULOS con una campo llamado CODIGO.

Relleno la tabla ARTICULOS con 5 filas con codigos del 1 al 5.

```
Nombre       |  Codigo

Articulo 1   |  1
Articulo 2   |  2
Articulo 3   |  3
Articulo 4   |  4
Articulo 5   |  5
```

Me pasan un listado de codigos a buscar (1,2,5,8,9) dentro de ARTICULOS y los saco con :

```
select * from ARTICULOS where Codigo IN (1,2,5,8,9)
```

Con esto consigo los datos delos codigos 1,2 y 5 pero el 8 y el 9 no estan en la tabla.

¿Cómo puedo saber los codigos del listado que me han pasado, que no estan en la tabla ARTICULOS? **Una consulta en SQL que me devuelva 8 y 9**

Comment: Dependiendo del Enunciado puedes bien crear estos Artículos con un INSERT a la tabla de ARTICULOS y después buscar con el IN para los parámetros de búsqueda que te indicaron dentro de tu sentencia SQL. Pero si solo te dicen buscar esos puedes responder que dichos artículos no están en la tabla enunciada.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma podría ser transformar los códigos a buscar en una tabla, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE CodigosBusqueda(CodigoBuscado INT)
INSERT INTO CodigosBusqueda(CodigoBuscado ) VALUES (1), (2), (5), (8), (9)

SELECT CASE WHEN A.Codigo IS NULL CONVERT(VARCHAR, C.CodigoBuscado) + ' NO Encontrado' 
            ELSE NULL END as EstatusBusqueda,
       A.*
       FROM CodigosBusqueda C
       LEFT JOIN ARTICULOS A
            ON A.Codigo = C.CodigoBuscado
```

Y hacer la búsqueda, mediante un `left join` a los artículos, con esto te aseguras de quedarte con todos los códigos buscados más los resultados de aquellos artículos que si se pudieron encontrar.

Answer (score 1):

con esto:

```
select codigo,ARTICULOS.nombre from (
(SELECT '' as nombre, 1 as codigo) union
(SELECT '' as nombre, 2 as codigo) union
(SELECT '' as nombre, 5 as codigo) union
(SELECT '' as nombre, 8 as codigo) union
(SELECT '' as nombre, 9 as codigo) ) as buscados
left join ARTICULOS using (codigo)
where Codigo IN (1,2,5,8,9);
```

resultado:

```
codigo  nombre  
1       Articulo 1
2       Articulo 2
5       Articulo 5
8       NULL
9       NULL
```

Lo mejor es evaluar la informacion despues con el lenguaje deprogramacion
un for que te lea lo buscado y compare con lo que encontraste

```
select * from ARTICULOS where Codigo IN (1,2,5,8,9)
```

usas esta y con un for buscas los codigos que no retorno como respuesta la consulta.